# Custom TableView Cell Missing in IOS Xcode 7 Using Swift 2

Tags: uitableview, xcode6, swift2, uitabbarcontroller, xcode7

In Xcode 7 I am developing custom tableView so their is a problem each 2 cells are unprinted after one. I do not know how this problem is coming from?

[image]

Here is my custom cell class:

import UIKit

class CustomCellTwo: UITableViewCell {

```
@IBOutlet weak var indx: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var dateOne: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var duaration: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var distance: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var ignitionOff: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var locationOne: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var dateTwo: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var ignitionOn: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var locationTwo: UILabel!






override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
}

override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
}
```

}

And here is my ViewControllerClass :
import Foundation
import UIKit

class TripReport : UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{

```
var dateTimeOn = [ "2016-Jan-20 11:36 AM","2016-Jan-20 11:25 AM","2016-Jan-20 11:15 AM","2016-Jan-20 11:05 AM","2016-Jan-20 11:04 AM","2016-Jan-20 11:02 AM","2016-Jan-20 11:00 AM","2016-Jan-20 10:57 AM","2016-Jan-20 10:57 AM","2016-Jan-20 10:53 AM"]

var dateTimeOff = [ "2016-Jan-20 11:36 AM","2016-Jan-20 11:25 AM","2016-Jan-20 11:15 AM","2016-Jan-20 11:05 AM","2016-Jan-20 11:04 AM","2016-Jan-20 11:02 AM","2016-Jan-20 11:00 AM","2016-Jan-20 10:57 AM","2016-Jan-20 10:57 AM","2016-Jan-20 10:53 AM"]

var eventOn = [ "IGNITION","IGNITION ON","IGNITION ON","IGNITION ON","IGNITION ON","IGNITION ON","IGNITION ON","IGNITION ON","IGNITION ON","IGNITION ON"]

var eventOff = [ "IGNITION OFF","IGNITION OFF","IGNITION OFF","IGNITION OFF","IGNITION OFF","IGNITION OFF","IGNITION OFF","IGNITION OFF","IGNITION OFF","IGNITION OFF"]

var duaration = [ "00 hr 00 min","00 hr 00 min","00 hr 00 min","00 hr 00 min","00 hr 00 min","00 hr 00 min","00 hr 00 min","00 hr 00 min","00 hr 00 min","00 hr 00 min"]

var distance = [ "00 km","00 km","00 km","00 km","00 km","00 km","00 km","00 km","00 km","00 km"]


 var locationOn = [ "7.88 KM SE of Police Line Constibilary, Faisalabad - Jaranwala Road, FAISALABAD, PUNJAB, PK","0.47 KM SE of Police Line Constibilary, Faisalabad - Jaranwala Road, FAISALABAD, PUNJAB, PK","0.99 KM SE of Police Line Constibilary, Faisalabad - Jaranwala Road, FAISALABAD, PUNJAB, PK","0.99 KM SE of Police Line Constibilary, Faisalabad - Jaranwala Road, FAISALABAD, PUNJAB, PK","0.99 KM SE of Police Line Constibilary, Faisalabad - Jaranwala Road, FAISALABAD, PUNJAB, PK","1.01 KM SE of Police Line Constibilary, Faisalabad - Jaranwala Road, FAISALABAD, PUNJAB, PK","1.16 KM SE of Police Line Constibilary, Faisalabad - Jaranwala Road, FAISALABAD, PUNJAB, PK","1.03 KM SE of Police Line Constibilary, Faisalabad - Jaranwala Road, FAISALABAD, PUNJAB, PK","0.98 KM SE of Police Line Constibilary, Faisalabad - Jaranwala Road, FAISALABAD, PUNJAB, PK","1.62 KM SE of Police Line Constibilary, Faisalabad - Jaranwala Road, FAISALABAD, PUNJAB, PK"]


 var locationOff = [ "7.88 KM SE of Police Line Constibilary, Faisalabad - Jaranwala Road, FAISALABAD, PUNJAB, PK","0.47 KM SE of Police Line Constibilary, Faisalabad - Jaranwala Road, FAISALABAD, PUNJAB, PK","0.99 KM SE of Police Line Constibilary, Faisalabad - Jaranwala Road, FAISALABAD, PUNJAB, PK","0.99 KM SE of Police Line Constibilary, Faisalabad - Jaranwala Road, FAISALABAD, PUNJAB, PK","0.99 KM SE of Police Line Constibilary, Faisalabad - Jaranwala Road, FAISALABAD, PUNJAB, PK","1.01 KM SE of Police Line Constibilary, Faisalabad - Jaranwala Road, FAISALABAD, PUNJAB, PK","1.16 KM SE of Police Line Constibilary, Faisalabad - Jaranwala Road, FAISALABAD, PUNJAB, PK","1.03 KM SE of Police Line Constibilary, Faisalabad - Jaranwala Road, FAISALABAD, PUNJAB, PK","0.98 KM SE of Police Line Constibilary, Faisalabad - Jaranwala Road, FAISALABAD, PUNJAB, PK","1.62 KM SE of Police Line Constibilary, Faisalabad - Jaranwala Road, FAISALABAD, PUNJAB, PK"]




@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    print("Trip Report Called")



}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 10;
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("celltwo", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomCellTwo
     print("table view cell")

    cell.dateOne.text = self.dateTimeOff[indexPath.row]
    cell.duaration.text = self.duaration[indexPath.row]
    cell.distance.text = self.distance[indexPath.row]
    cell.ignitionOn.text = self.eventOn[indexPath.row]
    cell.ignitionOff.text = self.eventOff[indexPath.row]
    cell.locationOne.text = self.locationOff[indexPath.row]
    cell.locationTwo.text = self.locationOn[indexPath.row]
    cell.dateOne.text = self.dateTimeOff[indexPath.row]
    cell.dateTwo.text = self.dateTimeOn[indexPath.row]

    cell.indx.text = "\(indexPath.row)";

    return cell
 }
```

}

Note : I have the same technique for other tableview and that is working perfect .
Now my both Views are joined in Tab Bar Controller ..